# Google App Engine Python: How to display textarea value in mail

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a html form with `<textarea name="message"></textarea>` and I get the value by `message  = self.request.get('message')`.

Then I do mail api

```
message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="abc@domain.com", subject="Testing")
message.to = 'bcd@domain.com'
message.html = """The Message: %s """ % (message)
message.send()
```

The problem is I can only see the "The Message:" in my email without the 'message' value, how do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the variable name 'message' for both the original text in the textarea, and the email you're sending. Try this:

```
text = self.request.get('message')
message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="abc@domain.com", subject="Testing") 
message.to = 'bcd@domain.com' 
message.html = """The Message: %s """ % (text) 
message.send()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the GAE mail api but you seem to reassign the `message` variable name to a new item, in this case an object, then you try to make the object the message body. :s

Try something like:

```
message = self.request.get('message')
mailer = mail.EmailMessage(sender="abc@domain.com", subject="Testing")
mailer.to = 'bcd@domain.com'
mailer.html = """The Message: %s """ % (message)
mailer.send()
```

In production you would probably also want to do a null check for the `message` variable's value.